# Executar Activity de um outro app

Tags: java, android

É possível executar uma Activity de um outro app? Não quero chamá-la através de um intent, algo parecido a isso:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends com.otherapp.app.ActivityName
{
     // Aqui vai conter o código original da Activity
}
```

Sei que é possível fazer isso com NativeActivity implementando os métodos originais dentro da Activity e carregando a biblioteca .so do app. Porém o app em questão não possui NativeActivity.

Minha intenção é fazer uma modificação em tempo de execução do app, por exemplo: Supondo que Activity do outro app tem o método getIcon(), sobrescrevendo ele na minha AnotherActivity(que é a mesma Activity do app) eu posso trocar o ícone do app.

Comment: Só para confirmar quer aceder a uma Activity de outra App? Isso não parece algo correto...nem sequer lógico